# Nagios3 configuration for sending simple text message on some port

Tags: nagios

I am developing an application and decided Nagios3 for performing monitoring stuff. But I am stuck at two points. I am using check_http plug-in for monitoring load on my service api. Now I want to perform below tasks.

1. I need to set a threshold in check_http for performing some task after crossing that threshold. I tried below command

'check_command  check_nrpe_1arg!check_service_api'

but it only tells me the load, not any threshold is set. while below one doesn't work.

'check_command  check_service_api!100!200'

2. I need to send simple text message on some port(my application).

I am new to Nagios, so please help me figuring out the solution except email notification stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is a check command that you can download called "notify_sms" that integrates with an API server hosted by a company called Esendex. They charge for their service but it works well.

Comment: Can I configure Nagios to send a message on a port?